# Bluemix, deploying ruby-on-rails using hub.jazz.net, error 'An application could not be detected by any available buildpack'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-cloud, ibm-jazz

I have created a Bluemix runtime Ruby-on-Rails. I am using IBM devops hub.jazz.net, and have setup the Build and Deploy to the bluemix application.

The Build and Deploy gives an error message - 'An application could not be detected by any available buildpack'

What are the steps to setup the deploy correctly. How do I troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Can you please give the steps you followed till now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are deploying using cf from your local setup

And the issue lies with some wrong entry made in manifest.yml. Please check it and add correct build pack. Sometimes Cloud Foundry can't detect the type of app you are running and when you push the app you need to tell it what kind of app it is. We can do that with some of the following commands.

cf buildpacks   -- to see list of available build packs

cf push appname -b ruby_buildpack  ---pushing app

Here is a link that can be helpful to you :

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-blograils-app/

Comment: Manish, I have copied the Manifest.yml, however I am not sure what is the minimum stuff needed in the manifest file. I have updated the project name and app name and when I run >  cf push bluemixstore -p  http://bluemixstore.stage1.mybluemix.net/ -m 512M, I get following error -Error reading manifest file:

Comment: Error reading manifest file-- it means that you have not formatted manifest.yml file properly.Please do format it properly as per manifest.yml specification.may be this link can help you to spot error in your yml file https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/18870/error-reading-manifest-file-expected-services-to-be-a-list-of-strings.html

Comment: I suppose I do need to provide the buildpack in the manifest file. How do I find out what to mention here for the runtime service that I am using. I do not see a mention in the doc link - https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/rails/index.html#rails

Answer (score 0):

I followed https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/11653/manifest-yml-what-are-the-mandatory-and-optional-fields.html for manifest.yml.

### >> cat manifest.yml

### minimum manifest file as in http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html

applications:
- name: bluemixstore
memory: 512M

I used command WITHOUT the hostname, it moved forward, and gave an error saying my space has run out.

> > cf push bluemixstore -m 512M

Comment: i don't think minimal memory would be 512mb,can you try with 256mb,even you can remove unwanted services from your bluemix dashboard to get more space available

Comment: As Akshay pointed out ..it seems there are multiple apps running in your account resulting in the consumption of 2G free(I assume you are using trail account) memory ..so please delete one of the app.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, Manish - for the space issue, I have reduced to 256M, still struggling with buildpack, see my comment above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506058/not-able-to-push-my-local-app-to-bluemix/27674490#27674490 - The buildpack name to use is mentioned in this link, Ruby: cf push appname -b ruby_buildpack

Comment: Can you run cf buildpacks on your system to see if ruby_buildpack is installed and also paste the complete error message by using cf logs appname --recent